# How to trigger snapshot for specific datasets only in Azure Data Share

Tags: azure

I have 20 datasets received in Azure Data Share. I already copied 10 of them into a filesystem in ADLS2 using manual Trigger Snapshot by mapping only 10. Now I need to Trigger Snapshot for the remaining 10 datasets into a new filesystem but dont want to include the earlier 10 datasets. Is this possible to only Trigger snapshot for specific datasets or do I need to remove the first 10 mappings?

Answer (score 0):

If you set up an incremental trigger it should get only the new ones.